# xampp can't FIND apache

Tags: xampp

I have been using xampp for some time with no problems. But today, when I try to run it, I get the error Problem detected: Apache Not Found! I have made no changes to any settings/directories that could have caused this error. The only thing that I did was copied a project into the htdocs folder. But deleting it from there makes no difference. Any help would be great!

```
12:30:24 PM  [main]     Initializing Control Panel

12:30:24 PM  [main]     Windows Version:  Enterprise  64-bit

12:30:24 PM  [main]     XAMPP Version: 8.1.6

12:30:24 PM  [main]     Control Panel Version: 3.3.0  [ Compiled: Apr 6th 2021 ]

12:30:24 PM  [main]     Running with Administrator rights - good!

12:30:24 PM  [main]     XAMPP Installation Directory: "d:\xampp\"

12:30:24 PM  [main]     Checking for prerequisites

12:30:24 PM  [main]     All prerequisites found

12:30:24 PM  [main]     Initializing Modules

12:30:24 PM  [Apache]   Problem detected: Apache Not Found!

12:30:24 PM  [Apache]   Disabling Apache buttons

12:30:24 PM  [Apache]   Run this program from your XAMPP root directory!

12:30:24 PM  [mysql]    XAMPP MySQL is already running on port 3306

12:30:24 PM  [main]     Starting Check-Timer

12:30:24 PM  [main]     Control Panel Ready
```

Comment: Do you have `d:\xampp\apache`?

Comment: Yes. It has been there and I haven't made any modifications to it at any point. There's 21 items in it.

Comment: Does `\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe` exist?

Comment: httpd.exe is missing

Comment: That explains why. Try to find httpd.exe (maybe it's elsewhere in the hard disk? was it moved to another drive?), then move it to the right place.

Comment: I have searched my system and it doesn't seem to be on it. No luck in the recycle bin either. I have found httpd.conf but I assume that's not what I'm concerned with right now? Is there any way to get it back on my system or recreate it?

Comment: Download a version that matches your xampp version, extract httpd from it, then copy it there. Reinstalling somewhere (if possible) should also give it back. But I am wondering why it disappeared at the first place? Maybe "antivirus"?